# How the outer array knows the inner array completed its iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, recursion

In Javascript how the outer array knows the inner array completed its iteration? as I am iterating the below array with recursive function want to know how the outer function or outer array knows the inner array completed the iteration.

```
 {
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "PQR"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "XYZ"
    },
    {
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "value": "ST"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "value": "UI"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "value": "5XYZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the recursive function to iterate the array.

Require the output like
ABC,PQR,XYZ,5XYZ
Within Group ST,UI

---

#### Edit1

```
var message = '';
var infoMessage = getMessageData(false);

function getMessageData(isGroup) {
  angular.forEach(rulesArray, function(v, k) {
      if (rulesArray.id === undefined) {
        message + = getMessageData(true);
      } else {
        message + = v.value;
        if (isGroup) {
          message + = 'Within Group' + v.value;
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you can try something like this:

#### Idea

- Sort array based on objects that have `rules` and push them back
- Loop over array and check

  - If object has `id`, concat `value` to response
  - If object has `rules`, use recursion and get response and concat it.

```js
var data = { "rules": [{ "id": 1, "value": "ABC" }, { "id": 2, "value": "PQR" }, { "id": 3, "value": "XYZ" }, { "rules": [{ "id": 10, "value": "ST" }, { "id": 12, "value": "UI" } ] }, { "id": 5,   "value": "5XYZ" } ] }

const key = 'rules';
data.rules.sort(function(a,b){
  return +(key in a) - +(key in b);
});

function getMessage(obj) {
  return obj.reduce(function (p, c, i, a){
    if('id' in c) {
      p += c.value + (i !== a.length -1 ? ', ': '');
    }
    
    if('rules' in c) {
      p += getMessage(c.rules);
    }
    return p;
  }, '')
}

console.log(getMessage(data.rules))
```

Comment: **Note:** This answer is based on partial understanding. If you think there is anything *incorrect/ unwanted/ not required*, please comment it along with your vote. Have a good day!

Comment: Sorry it didn't give proper answer the expected answer is    ABC,PQR,XYZ, Within Group ST,UI ,5XYZ

Comment: @aryan Both the answers are based on a partial understanding of your required output. If you can provide a sample input with expected output and in proper format, it would be easy for us to help you

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for genuine guidelines, I require the logic that my outer array know when the inner array complete its works, so will proceed my work. Please use this data var data = { rules: [{ id: 1, value: "ABC" }, { id: 2, value: "PQR" }, { id: 3, value: "XYZ" }, { rules: [{ id: 10, value: "ST" }, { id: 12, value: "UI" }] }, { id: 5, value: "5XYZ" },{ rules: [{ id: 1022, value: "ST2" }, { id: 122, value: "UI22" }] }] }; Expected answer is ABC,PQR,XYZ, Within Group ST,UI ,5XYZ

Answer (score 0):

You you take a queue for collecting and processing all items of `rules` with a counter for inserting the group phrase.

```js
function iterate(array) {
    var queue = array.slice(),
        group = array.length,
        temp,
        result = '';

    while (queue.length) {
        temp = queue.shift();
        if (temp.rules) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(queue, temp.rules);
            continue;
        }
        if (--group) {
            result += (result && ', ') + temp.value;
            continue;
        }
        result += ' Within Group ' + temp.value;
    }
    return result;
}

var data = { rules: [{ id: 1, value: "ABC" }, { id: 2, value: "PQR" }, { id: 3, value: "XYZ" }, { rules: [{ id: 10, value: "ST" }, { id: 12, value: "UI" }] }, { id: 5, value: "5XYZ" }] };

console.log(iterate(data.rules));
```

Comment: It failed when use following array - 
var data = { rules: [{ id: 1, value: "ABC" }, { id: 2, value: "PQR" }, { id: 3, value: "XYZ" }, { rules: [{ id: 10, value: "ST" }, { id: 12, value: "UI" }] }, { id: 5, value: "5XYZ" },{ rules: [{ id: 1022, value: "ST2" }, { id: 122, value: "UI22" }] }] };

Comment: @aryan, what means failed? what do you get, and what do you want?

Comment: Thanks Nina for your extreme help ,I require the logic that my outer array know when the inner array complete its works, so will proceed my work. Please use this data var data = { rules: [{ id: 1, value: "ABC" }, { id: 2, value: "PQR" }, { id: 3, value: "XYZ" }, { rules: [{ id: 10, value: "ST" }, { id: 12, value: "UI" }] }, { id: 5, value: "5XYZ" },{ rules: [{ id: 1022, value: "ST2" }, { id: 122, value: "UI22" }] }] }; Expected answer is ABC,PQR,XYZ, Within Group ST,UI ,5XYZ

Comment: what happens to `'ST2'` and `'UI22'`?